# How to make a method execute methods synchronously

Tags: swift, asynchronous, synchronization

I tried using DispatchQueue and DispatchGroup but its still asynchronous, I also tried both dispatchQueue.Async and dispathQueue.sync and neither have worked.

myFunc is a function called in the init() which itself calls 2 functions, getArrOneData() annd getArrTwoData([ArrOneType]).

The first function downloads ArrOneType data from firestore and returns an array which is initialised to a field.

The second function uses the downloaded data/field from the first function to initialise a field  in ArrTwoType while simultaneously downloading other relevent ArrTwoType data from firestore to return as an array.

So the Problem is its still asynchronous. How do I use DispatchQueue and DispatchGroup correctly in this scenario?

thanks

note: get arrTwoData is mainly psuedocode

```
func myFunc(){
        let group = DispatchGroup()
        let dispatchQueue = DispatchQueue.global(qos: .default)
        group.enter()
        dispatchQueue.sync {
            self.arrOne = self.getArrOneData()//getArrOneData gets data from firestore
            group.leave()
        }

dispatchQueue.sync {
        group.enter()
    self.arrTwo = self.getArrTwoData(inputArr: self.arrOne)//getArrTwoData gets data from firestore 

    group.leave()
         }
    }

//ArrOneType is an array field in ArrTwoType
func getArrTwoData(inputArr: [ArrOneType]) -> [ArrTwoType]{

var result = [ArrTwoType]()

//retrieving data from firestore, code excluded...
    for document in querySnapshot!.documents {
   let data = document.data()

name = data["Name"] as? String ?? "Name Unknown"

//returns an array which is a subset of inputArr filtered by name, however
//I dont think the inputArr is populated at this point when I run the program
var field2:[ArrOneType] = someFunc(name, inputArr)

var x = ArrTwoType(name: name, field2: field2)

result.append(x)
    }
  }
}
return result
}
```

Comment: Why do you want to load data synchronously ? That's dangerous and it will block the main queue, thus your application would freeze. I suggest doing an asynchronous retrieval of the first function then in the completion block, call the second function with the result of the first function.

Comment: @AliZahr based on your comment, this is what I found, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59619673/how-to-call-function-after-async-requests-finish-in-swiftui is this what you meant? (Im using swiftUI)

Comment: @AliZahr I just need the data to download from firestore once and its never called again after

Comment: Regardless if it's SwiftUI or not, it's a general iOS Principle. Write one function to download the data you want and in its completion block pass the data to the other function, you can save the data in a local variable so that you dont need to retrieve the data that you only need once.

Comment: @AliZahr okay thank you, I'm fairly new to swift and ios development and I just want to clarify, is a completion block the same thing as a completion handler?

Comment: Yes they are the same.

Answer (score 0):

If you have two requests, one which uses the response from one to prepare the next, the idea is to use `@escaping` completion handler closures for all asynchronous methods, e.g.

```
func getArrayOneData(completion: @escaping (Result<[ArrayOneType], Error>) -> Void) {
    someAsynchronousMethod {
        let values: [ArrayOneType] = ...
        completion(.success(values))
    }
}

func getArrayTwoData(for typeOneValues: [ArrayOneType], completion: @escaping (Result<[ArrayTwoType], Error>) -> Void) {
    someAsynchronousMethod(for: typeOneValues) {
        let values: [ArrayTwoType] = ...
        completion(.success(values))
    }
}
```

Then you can do things like:

```
func getEverything(completion: @escaping (Result<[ArrayTwoType], Error>) -> Void) {
    getArrayOneData { result in
        switch result {
        case .failure(let error):
            print(error)

        case .success(let typeOneValues):
            getArrayTwoData(for: typeOneValues) { result in
                switch result {
                case .failure(let error):
                    print(error)

                case .success(let typeTwoValues):
                    completion(.success(typeTwoValues))
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Note, no dispatch groups needed. Having added completion handlers to the asynchronous methods, we can just call the second method from the completion handler of the first.